# Why is my simpleDateFormat screwing up the day of the week?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a date. When I use the following date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM d");
```

With the string "Monday, May 19", doing

```
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateString));
```

and pulling out the day of week in short format, I'm getting "Tue"! Cal's day of week seems to be set to 3. Any idea why? It's coming up with May for month and 19 for day, but it wants to say Tuesday for day of week, and May 19 is definitely a Monday in my locale.

Comment: Its `Tue May 19 00:00:00 GMT 1970` Try with `sdf.parse("Monday, May 19")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`parse` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-)'s Javadocs state:

> All of the calendar's date-time fields are cleared before parsing, and the calendar's default values of the date-time fields are used for any missing date-time information. For example, the year value of the parsed Date is 1970 with GregorianCalendar if no year value is given from the parsing operation.

You don't supply a year, so it defaults to `1970`, and the day of the week follows.

Answer (score 1):

Because May 19, 1970 was a Tuesday, and it's defaulting the year for some reason.